# Excel Numbers with two decimal places

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote the following simple code which takes the input from user for N1 and N2 and adds them up and gives them as output (N3).There is an issue with this that, it rounds up each of the input instead of just taking the numbers.

Easy example: N1 = 25.5, N2 = 25.5 Right Answer = 51 but the answer it gives is 52. I am new to programming so would appreciate any help I can get.

I want it to display N3 up to 6 decimal places without rounding individual inputs from N1 and N2 at the time of taking inputs.

```
Sub InputVariable()

    Dim N1 As Integer
    Dim N2 As Integer
    Dim N3 As Integer
    N1 = InputBox("Enter 1st number")
    N2 = InputBox("Enter 2nd number")
    N3 = N1 + N2
    MsgBox ("Your total is " & N3)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `Double` data type. If you use an integer type (`Integer` or `Long`) it will round the numbers at `N1 = InputBox(...)` because it can't store non-integer values in the variables.

edit: `Double` stands for double precision (8 byte) compared to single precision (4 byte). It is interesting to note that because `Double` uses the binary number format it can't store exact values like 0.1 (just like the decimal system can't express 1/3 no matter how many digits you have).

If you need to do really precise calculations with decimal numbers, there's the `Decimal` format that you can use. You can't actually declare it but you can convert a number to decimal and store it in a `Variant`. See this example:

```
Sub precisionTest()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dbl As Double
    Dim dblResult As Double
    Dim dec As Variant
    Dim decResult As Variant

    dblResult = 0
    decResult = 0
    dbl = 0.00001
    dec = CDec(0.00001)
    For i = 1 To 100000
    dblResult = dblResult + dbl
    decResult = decResult + dec
    Next i
    MsgBox "Double result: " & dblResult & vbCr & "Decimal result: " & decResult
End Sub
```

edit2: **Rounding and formatting of numbers:** You can use the `Format` function to create strings of your number without changing the value (for display purposes only). Valid formats look like "0.##" where `0` means the decimal place is always displayed and `#` means it's displayed if it's non-zero:

```
Sub formatTest()
    Dim dbl As Double
    Dim dbl2 As Double
    Dim dbl3 As Double
    dbl = 1.234
    dbl2 = 1.2
    dbl3 = 0.1
    MsgBox "Format(1.234,""0.##"") = " & Format(dbl, "0.##") & vbCr _
    & "Format(1.234,""0.00"") = " & Format(dbl, "0.00") & vbCr _
    & "Format(1.2,""0.##"") = " & Format(dbl2, "0.##") & vbCr _
    & "Format(1.2,""0.00"") = " & Format(dbl2, "0.00") & vbCr _
    & "Format(0.1,""#.##"") = " & Format(dbl3, "#.##") & vbCr _
    & "Format(0.1,""0.00"") = " & Format(dbl3, "0.00") & vbCr
End Sub
```

If you want to actually round your numbers, use `Round(number,decimalplaces)`

Comment: @InWoods I edited in some more info about the format function

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @arcadeprecinct it works perfectly and thank you for explaining in such detail. I really learnt a lot :)

Comment: I think it's worth to mention that patterns with `#` always leave decimal separator (in my case `,`) in result, like `Format(0,"0.##")` displays `0,` and `Format(0,"#.##")` shows `,`

Answer (score 1):

As InWoods mentioned, you need N1, N2 and N3 to be double types, then you can cast the output in the print statement, like this:

```
MsgBox ("Your total is " & Format(N3, "Standard"))
```

The standard formatting includes two decimal places.

Comment: This works perfectly for another issue I was facing. Thank you:) Could you tell me if there is a dictionary that we can refer to to find the various format values or is it through experience that you said it should be standard. Ty for the help once again.

Comment: Not that I know of, although you can mess around with the format in Excel to see what the ouput becomes. Write a few numbers in a cell, then go to the Home-ribbon -> Number Format (dropdown list) -> "More Number Formats" (at the bottom) -> "Custom" (In the Category list) -> Then select or edit the type until you're satisfied.

Comment: @Thanks I will give it a try :) There is so much to learn for me :D